# sed in bash scripting troubleshooting

Tags: bash, sed, scripting, variable

I've got the following problem regarding to sed command. What I wish to do is:

```
sed '1 d' filename.fa | sed "1i\>filename\n" > filename_Edited.fa
```

where the file frist line is replaced by ">filename". This is done in 2 steps: deleting first line and then inserting a new one which contains the desired ">text". The command works as it is wirtten above if it is typed directly into the console (w/o  variables). However, I need this command integrated in the following script where filename is now depending on a variable:

```
#!/bin/bash

CODE=`cut -c 7-21 Data.txt`

cd ../FASTA_SEC/
 for i in ${CODE}
 do
 sed '1 d' ${CODE}.fa | sed "1i\>${CODE}\n" > ${CODE}_Edited.fa
 done
```

I get the following error when this script is ran for each for loop iteration:

```
try: line 8: ${CODE}_Edited.fa: ambiguous redirect
```

I dont get whats wrong in sed sintaxis orin the overall script, Aparently it should work but it does not. Any clue?

I have also tried to run the script without pipped part, only executing the sed which deletes first line from the text:

```
#!/bin/bash

CODE=`cut -c 7-21 Data.txt`

cd ../FASTA_SEC/
 for i in ${CODE}
 do
 sed '1 d' ${CODE}.fa > ${CODE}_Edited.fa
 done
```

However, it returns the former error again!

Thank you for yr help!!

**.fa format are known as fasta which are a kind of plain text format used in DNA sequences

Comment: `for i in ${CODE}` -> you probably want to use `$i` (or `${i}` if you prefer) in the loop body, not `${CODE}`. I guess this is the source of your "ambiguous redirect" error

Comment: yush true want an error! i got stuk there XD oki the script Works with ${i} lel.

Answer (score 2):

It might be simpler to not use `sed` for the prepend, but rather `cat`:

```
#!/bin/bash
header=$(mktemp)
scratch=$(mktemp)
trap "rm -f $header $scratch" EXIT

cd ../FASTA_SEC/
for CODE in $(cut -c 7-21 Data.txt); do
    echo ">${CODE}_" > $header
    if [[ -r "${CODE}.fa" ]]; then
        sed '1d' "${CODE}.fa" > $scratch
        cat $header $scratch > ${CODE}_Edited.fa
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank u Dope it Works like a charm. Could  u pls explain briefly what the condition inside if loop? ^^"

Comment: It's just a quick sanity check to make sure there's a readable file matching the pattern.